# Possibility of Hack-rf one working on full duplex mode

Tags: signal-processing, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, software-defined-radio

I am working with hack-rf one and GNU radio. I have one hack-rf one device and i am trying to transmit and receive signals continuously. Is there any module in GNU radio which makes it possible?

1. Currently i have a flowchart for receive and one for transmit.
2. I am using selector block but manual switching isnt working properly.

I need to send and receive the same signals after reflection and study the difference. 
Any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that is physically impossible for the device: No, no software on this earth can do that for you.

Comment: Completely different question. Please ask separately.

Comment: ask a new question, please.